# PHP MySQL Update info

Tags: php, mysql

I can't find a fix for my problem. I need to update a data from my MySQL Database, but my changePin.php is not working.

This is my changePin.php

```
<?php

require_once '../includes/DbOperations.php';
$response = array();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='PUT'){
    if(isset($_POST['cardno']) and isset($_POST['pin'])){
        $db = new DbOperations();
        if($db->changePin($_POST['cardno'], $_POST['pin'])){
            $response['error'] = false;
            $response['message'] = "Pin successfully change";
        }
        else{
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = "Invalid Card Number or Pin";
        }
    }
    else{
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
    }
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

When I try to use Postman builder with PUT as method and key of cardno and pin, it gives me

```
{"error":true,"message":"Required fields are missing"}
```

Comment: PUT data will not be in `$_POST`, so both of those `isset` checks evaluate to false.

Comment: `DbOperations` actually isn't relevant to this problem. If you're getting the response from the `else` block, it's never used.

Comment: There's no need to put "Help" in your question title. Obviously you're seeking help because you're asking a question.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: @tadman is that _clippy_? I haven't seen him in a while.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yeah, he's back to point out things like this.

Comment: @tadman I barely recognized him without his eyeballs.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Not sure how to add eyeballs. Certainly need them!